# jQuery appendTo() w/ Selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

So I've added four elements to a page that are separate from the Wordpress loop. I'm using jQuery appendto() to add them within the list of posts (loop). It works fine except for the last one... it seems to not be able to select it using last-child or only-child or nth-child. The other 3 elements are selected and moved perfectly fine using last-child(#).I've tried everything I can think of. What do you think?

Of course, once the 3 elements are moved I suppose to last one left is no longer considered a last-child or first-child?... but only-child doesn't work either...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var toApp1 = $(".recent_updates > .fp_post:nth-child(4)"),
        toApp2 = $(".recent_updates > .fp_post:nth-child(7)"),
        toApp3 = $(".recent_updates > .fp_post:nth-child(10)"),
        toApp4 = $(".recent_updates > .fp_post:nth-child(13)");
    var ad1 = $(".recent_updates > #skippingAds:nth-last-child(4)"),
        ad2 = $(".recent_updates > #skippingAds:nth-last-child(3)"),
        ad3 = $(".recent_updates > #skippingAds:nth-last-child(2)"),
        ad4 = $(".recent_updates > #skippingAds:last");
    ad3.appendTo(toApp3);
    ad2.appendTo(toApp2);
    ad1.appendTo(toApp1);
    ad4.appendTo(toApp4);
});
```

UPDATED CODE: (still no working with classes rather than IDs (good point out)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var toApp1 = $(".recent_updates > .fp_post:nth-child(4)"),
        toApp2 = $(".recent_updates > .fp_post:nth-child(7)"),
        toApp3 = $(".recent_updates > .fp_post:nth-child(10)"),
        toApp4 = $(".recent_updates > .fp_post:nth-child(13)");
    var ad1 = $(".skippingAds:nth-last-child(4)"),
        ad2 = $(".skippingAds:nth-last-child(3)"),
        ad3 = $(".skippingAds:nth-last-child(2)"),
        ad4 = $(".skippingAds:last-child");
    ad3.appendTo(toApp3);
    ad2.appendTo(toApp2);
    ad1.appendTo(toApp1);
    ad4.appendTo(toApp4);
});
```

Comment: IDs should be unique, so there should only be 1 `#skippingAds` anyway.

Comment: You should set up a jsfiddle with some example HTML (minimal example). Hard to tell without that.

Answer (score 2):

Your seem to be having duplicate `IDs` in your document which causes your HTML to be invalid. When your HTML is not valid you will get inconsistent behavior from browser to browser as there's no specification for handling invalid HTML, and therefore no browser is bound to adhere to that specification.

I would suggest that you change all your `skippingAds` IDs to classes and then you can use class selectors.

Comment: It may not be the issue but you always want to have valid HTML. You just want to get that out of the way anyhow.

Comment: Nvm ID is the issue, http://jsfiddle.net/DNLJJ/6/ targeting the p will work but targeting the id will not

Comment: That's a good confirmation. An id selector is meant to return at most 1 element. One browser may return the first while another may return the last, when several elements have the same ID.

Comment: nah, the #IDs work fine in this instance even if duplicates but yes I did change to classes since its more proper. However, did not solve the main issue.

Comment: It's not good to gamble with your life! :) How many browsers did you test with? If it worked in browser A there's no guarantee it will work with browser B. **VALID HTML IS A GOOD FOUNDATION** any time :)

Answer (score 0):

try last-child

```
ad4 = $(".recent_updates > #skippingAds:last-child");
```

Comment: That should not make a difference